# how to pass multi sereis data with dual y axis chart in highchart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

i am having high charts with dual y axis, i have variable called sereis0 with multiple values stored in a array.

able to pass single value in series, but not able to pass multiple series in data when using dual y axis. Please help me to solve the issue.

i have tried with

```
var k = 0;var category0 = new Array();var data0 = new Array();var series0 = new Array();var strarr = new Array();
        for(var i=0;i<str.length-1;i++){
            var strarr = str[i].split('$');
            category0[k] = strarr[0];data0[k] = strarr[1].split('|').join(',');
            series0[k] = {name: category0[k],data: JSON.parse("[" + data0[k] + "]") };
k++;

}

data: JSON.parse("[" + series0 + "]"),
```

but it didn't work, I am not able to post the series0 array as i am getting values from database.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f5ZhA/ , this link with single data array, i need to pass multiple series

Answer (score 0):

Multiple `data` arrays are not supported by Highcharts, you need to create separate series: http://jsfiddle.net/f5ZhA/1/

Comment: Thanks for your update. but i am willing to pass the data with this command data: JSON.parse("[" + series0 + "]"), in x axis, even for single y axis also passed like series: series0, its working, when using multiple axis we have to pass the series0 in data method, so not getting

Comment: Why JSON parse? Remove that from all places. Use simple: `data: [series0]`, `data: [data0[k]]` etc.